# How to make Angular and Spring Boot work together inside docker?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, deployment, docker-compose

I have my Angular frontend and Spring Boot backend in separate Github repositories. I am new to docker, I know how to build docker images for both separately and have also read about docker-compose to integrate the two, but having both the frontend and backend components in different repositories, I am not quite sure how to build a docker-compose that combines both the front end and back end docker images.

Comment: You don’t do that with Docker Compose. You’ll need to make a Dockerfile that puts the output of both in the same container in a way you want them to be

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `angular:latest` and a `spring-boot:latest` docker image, and your frontend app in `. /frontend` and backend in `. /backend` (those being git repositories)

You can use Docker compose to create your deployment :

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    image: angular:latest
    volumes:
       - ./frontend:/front
    command: <the right command to serve your app>
   ... [any other useful option, like ports, etc] 

  backend:
    image: spring-boot:latest
    volumes: 
       - ./backend:/back
    command: java -jar /back/target/your.jar #or something
   .. [any useful option]
```

**Upsides** : quick to deploy for testing, code is being updated on the go

**Downsides** : depending on what you put inside your directories,it might be too much, and you loose the "package" sense of an image

**Other solution** : create Docker images directly from Github with a Dockerfile that copy the packaged version of your app inside an image and launch it. You can even use Github actions to automate it.

Docker build allows you to build from a Github remote context.You can leverage that.

**Upsides** : you get an app packaged in a docker image, self sufficient and ready to deploy, in an automated way

**Downsides** : not the fastest solution when you dev (but it is balanced by the quality you might get from your CI/CD pipeline if you do it correctly), a little steeper learning curve (but not that much)

Comment: Does that work for you ? Did you find a solution ?